# Executing two php variables in mysql where query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause

my html form ->

```
<form action="where.php" method="post">
    <h2 align="center" style="color: white;"> Search Challan </h2>
    <table border="1"  bgcolor="grey" align="center">   
        <tr>
            <td align="center"> Search a Challan Details . Enter the Challan no below :</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"align="middle" ></td> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="squery" style="width:142px;" >
                    <option value="challan_no">Challan no </option>
                    <option value="product_name">Product Name</option>
                    <option value="Buyer">buyer</option>
                    <option value="Employee Responsible">Employee</option>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="search" >
            </td>       
        </tr>      
    </tr>
</form>
```

where.php ->

```
<?php
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbusername='root';
    $dbuserpass='';
    $dbname='inventory';

    //connect to the mysql database server.
    $con = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);

    if (!$con ) die ("unable to connect : ". mysql_error());

    mysql_selectdb("$dbname",$con ) ; 

    $user_req = $_REQUEST['squery'] ;     //colomn name
    $req_id = $_REQUEST['search'] ;       // 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM challan WHERE '$user_req' = $req_id  ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    if (!$result) die ("DAtabase acces faild bc : ". mysql_error());       

    $rows = mysql_numrows($result);   

    for ($j=0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        echo "<TABLE border=1 bgcolor=grey align=center width=500px float=left>"   ;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=center>Challan no :  </td>";
        echo " <td> $row[0]  </td>";
        echo " </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td align=center>Challan Date : </td>"; 
        echo " <td> $row[1]  </td>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td align=center>Product Name :   </td> ";
        echo " <td> $row[2]  </td>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td align=center>Product qty :  </td> " ;
        echo " <td> $row[3]  </td>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td align=center> Buyer : </td> " ;
        echo " <td> $row[4]  </td>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td align=center>Employee Responsible :  </td> " ;
        echo " <td> $row[5]  </td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
?>
```

Its output is just blank.  I'm unable to identify where I am going wrong.

Comment: please cleanup your code a bit before you post it here...

Comment: A blank page usually means there was a fatal error in PHP and you don't have error reporting turned on. Try putting this at the beginning of your script: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` followed by  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: In the query `SELECT * FROM challan WHERE '$user_req' = $req_id` you used apostrophes for the column name. Use this: `SELECT * FROM challan WHERE $user_req = '$req_id'`

Comment: Have you got set `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = on` in your php.ini? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Also use `echo` and `var_dump()` at intervals in your code to see what is being evaluated.

Comment: Your HTML is missing a bunch of closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

blank screen indicates that has occurred a fatal error and php was unable to continue script execution, you can run this in the top of your scripts to  errors should be printed to the screen as part of the output.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```